# Flex custom component disappears

Tags: apache-flex, custom-component

I have a problem with a custom component based on a Group. Actually, I want to create a section component (a container with a border and a title). I created a path so that the border doesn't hide the label (title):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Group xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
         xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
         xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">

    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Placer ici les éléments non visuels (services et objets de valeur, par exemple). -->
    </fx:Declarations>

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            [Bindable]
            public var title:String;
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:states>
        <s:State name="normal" />
        <s:State name="disabled" />
    </s:states>

    <!-- border --> 
    <s:Path id="border" left="3" right="3" top="5" bottom="5"
            data="M 5 0
            L {this.titleDisplay.left-7} 0
            M {this.titleDisplay.left+this.titleDisplay.width} 0
            L {this.width-5} 0
            C {this.width} 0 {this.width} 0 {this.width} 5
            L {this.width} {this.height-5}
            C {this.width} {this.height} {this.width} {this.height} {this.width-5} {this.height}
            L 5 {this.height}
            C 0 {this.height} 0 {this.height} 0 {this.height-5}
            L 0 5
            C 0 0 0 0 5 0
            ">
        <s:filters>
            <s:GlowFilter alpha="0.5" blurX="10" blurY="10" color="0xffffff"
                          quality="5" strength="6"/>
        </s:filters>
        <s:stroke>     
            <s:SolidColorStroke id="borderStroke" weight="1" color="#ffffff" alpha="0.5"/>
        </s:stroke>
    </s:Path>


    <s:Label id="titleDisplay" maxDisplayedLines="1"
             left="{this.width*0.08}" top="0" bottom="0" minHeight="30"
             verticalAlign="top" textAlign="left" fontWeight="bold"
             text="{title}">
        <s:filters>
            <s:GlowFilter alpha="0.5" blurX="10" blurY="10" color="0xffffff"
                          quality="5" strength="6"/>
        </s:filters>
    </s:Label>

    <!--- @copy spark.components.SkinnableContainer#contentGroup -->
    <s:Group id="contentGroup" width="95%" height="95%" minWidth="0" minHeight="0">
    </s:Group>

</s:Group>
```

My component looks great with no child. But when I tried something like:

```
<component:MySectionComponent>
   <s:Button id="mybtn"/>
</component:MySectionComponent>
```

Nothing else than the button is displayed. I tried changing my Group modified component to a SkinnableContainer but did the same. Furthermore if I add the Button directly into the MySectionComponent contentGroup, it works fine. I just dont know what might be causing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By putting that Button inside the MySectionComponent tag, you effectively override the value of the 'mxmlChildren' property of the MySectionComponent instance. Hence all the children that were there in the base class disappear and are replaced with just the one Button.

What you should do to fix this issue:

- extend SkinnableContainer instead of Group
- create a skin class (e.g. MySectionComponentSkin) in which you copy the code that is now in your Group.
- assign the skin to your SkinnableContainer

Like this:

```
<component:MySectionComponent skinClass="MySectionComponentSkin">
    <s:Button id="mybtn"/>
</component:MySectionComponent>
```

What is different here is that when you use SkinnableContainer, whatever you assign to its 'mxmlChildren' property will be transferred to the 'mxmlChildren' property of the 'contentGroup' in its skin.

If your MySectionComponent is now left with no additional code, you can altogether skip it and use SkinnableContainer directly:

```
<s:SkinnableContainer skinClass="MySectionComponentSkin">
    <s:Button id="mybtn"/>
</s:SkinnableContainer>
```

But I see that you have a 'title' in the component, so you will need some additional coding. Your MySectionComponent should look something like this:

```
public class MySectionComponent extends SkinnableContainer {
    [Bindable] public var title;
}
```

And now you can access that property from within the skin. First make sure the skin knows its host component:

```
<s:Skin xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">

<fx:Metadata>
    [HostComponent("MySectionComponent")]
</fx:Metadata>

...
```

Then access the 'title' property like so:

```
<s:Label text="{hostComponent.title}" />
```

and remove the 'title' property from your skin class (as you probably copy/pasted it along with the other code).

Comment: It's possible that Panel could also do what the OP wants, with a custom skin.